# Pull a single file from the origin (Git)

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

Im using eclipse plugin **EGit** in my project.And I have **deleted the a file** in my eclipse **workspace**.Through eclipse how can I pull that **specific single file** again to my workspace? What are steps to do that in **egit**?

As you can see I have deleted the member class. :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the project. Go to `Replace With -> HEAD Revision` this will overwrite local changes

Comment: Thnx man!. And also there is a eclipse view tab named "Git Staging".From there we can overwrite local changes.Again thank u very much for the answer :)